# Customize Admin template in Shoppe

Tags: customization, admin, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.2

I am working on a Rails project to build an E-commerce website. I am using [Shoppe gem](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe). I refer [Tryshoppe](http://tryshoppe.com/) website.

As shoppe gem mounts an Admin interface for us but as per my requirements I want to customize it. I am also interested in changing the layout of admin interface.

For example, We can generate views in `Device gem` and customize it.

Can we generate views and mailer templates to override the default template of Shoppe gem?

Comment: if you intend to edit it heavily, don't use it as a gem, copy it inside your library and mount it as an engine with full path http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#hooking-into-an-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge the only way would be to clone the gem repo to your github and edit the gemfile as needed.  Then add the gem to your app but link it to your github repo for that gem.

This would basically translate to:

```
gem 'shoppe', :git => 'git://github.com/<username>/shoppe.git'
```

Comment: I am doing the same! Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

There is overriding decorators exist in Rails also for such cases:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#improving-engine-functionality